# ¿Cómo puede listar los ficheros de un git commit sin que aparezcan las diferencias?

Tags: git

alguien sabe cómo listar sólo los ficheros de un commit en concreto? el comando **git show** muestra también las diferencias, y la necesidad es que sólo muestre el listado de ficheros, para luego pasar este listado por **xargs** por ejemplo

Comment: Hola Ricardo, bienvenido a la comunidad de stackoverflow **en español**. Te recomiendo, además, pasarte por [¿cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

Obtenido de una pregunta muy similar en [StackOverflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424071/how-to-list-all-the-files-in-a-commit):

```
git show --pretty="" --name-only <commitID>
```

El parámetro final es opcional, si no lo pones asume el último commit hecho.

Este comando es una versión "amigable" del comando:

```
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r <commitID>
```

que está más pensado para usarse en scripts

Comment: g r a c c i e ! !